# Two onclick on one element

Tags: javascript

I have a simple code to delete data from the database,and I want a warning message to appear before deleting. the code works fine when I put one onclick and when I put two only the first onclick works.

and I need to onclick  one for the warning message and the other for delet.php page.

```
<form><input type="button" value="delete" onclick="return confirm('Really delete?');" onClick='window.location.href="delete.php?id= <?php echo  $id; ?>"' ></form>
```

Comment: You can combine the two into one onClick.

Comment: As mentioned above, you can only have a single onClick, but I don't think that's really the issue here. What you want to do is have the confirmation popup call the delete if appropriate. If you simply combine the two, you will always call your delete page regardless of the option chosen in the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this with an if clause:

```
<form>
  <input type="button" value="delete" onclick="
    if(confirm('Really delete?')) {
      window.location.href='delete.php?id=<?php echo  $id; ?>';
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
   ">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would handle it:

```
<input type="button" value="delete" 
   onclick="confirmDelete('<?php echo  $id; ?>');">
```

Then elsewhere in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function confirmDelete(id) {
        if(confirm('Really delete?')) {
            window.location.href= "delete.php?id=" + id;
        }
  }
</script>
```

Notice I removed the `<form>` element. If this is the only context this is in, the `<form>` element is unnecessary since you're not actually filling out a form, just clicking a button. If there is more context you didn't include in your question, then it might be relevant to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use one onClick. But there's a way to do what you want in only one ;)

```
<form>
  <input type="button" value="delete" onclick="
    if(confirm('Really delete?')){ 
      window.location.href=\"delete.php?id= <?php echo  $id; ?>\" 
    }else{ 
      return false; 
    }" />
 </form>
```